# Alert to show from controller

Tags: jquery, json, jquery-ui, asp.net-mvc-4

I am working on a user management application where in I need to add a user in db.

```
When click of a button in client screen ( index.cshtml ), a JQuery dialog will popup and fill the user details ( Adduser.cshtml (partial class) ) . On click of Save button the data will pass to controller validate it and call the model method to add the user. If the user already exists the webservice will return error message. In controller the exception will be catched and wants to show it to user.
```

After the exception I need to show the error message as an alert or write it on the AddUser.cshtml. The below are the various options I tried out and issues with that

1. return Partial("AddUser", model ) - The problem here is the Adduser.cshtml is showing in a separate page and not showing as a dialog in client screen.
2. Storing the exception message in TemData, return to RedirectToAction("index") and trying to load the Adduser.cshtml on page load - The problem here is the JQuery dialog goes blank.
3. return Json { new success = true } - The problem is the message is showing separate page and not giving the exact error message.
4. return content(alert(errmessage)) - The alert message is showing but when click on ok button showing a blank separate page.
5. Tried to call model method using Javascript in Adduser.cshtml - Not sure to call the model method for adding user. If success how the redirectionto client screen will work from Adduser.cshtml

Please can anyone help me on this.

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult AddClient(ClientModel mCust, string command)
    {
        var clientObj = new Metadata.Client.Service.Client();
        ClientModel clientModel = new ClientModel();

        if (command == "Save")
        {

            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return PartialView(mCust);
            }


            clientObj.ClientType = new Metadata.Client.Service.ClientType();
            clientObj.ClientName = mCust.Client.ClientName;
            clientObj.ClientCode = mCust.Client.ClientCode;
            if (mCust.ClientTypeSelectId != 0)
                clientObj.ClientType.ClientTypeId = (mCust.ClientTypeSelectId) - 1;
            else
                clientObj.ClientType.ClientTypeId = mCust.ClientTypeSelectId;

            try
            {
                clientObj = clientModel.AddNewClient(clientObj);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                //TempData["addclient"] = null;
                //TempData["addclient"] = ex.Message;
                //mCust.SetClientTypeList();
                //mCust.WebResponse.Message = ex.Message;
                //return PartialView(mCust);

                // we're gonna show this in a ValidationSummary
                ModelState.AddModelError("", ex.Message);
                return PartialView("AddClient", mCust);

            }
        }

        return RedirectToAction("Index");

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not the change in action you should look for. Basically you should post the form with ajax and on the callback method, you can check for the 'success' or 'error' and display the dialog from there it self.

You have to have some callback after ajax completion like:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
function onSuccess(result){if(result.get_data()=='error'){alert('error'); }}
</script>
```

To extend it even further, you can send your message from the controller like this "error|error_message". and this way you can check if it was success or error by splitting the result.get_data() by the character '|' and show your passed message.

Comment: Thanks Gaurav I will try this and let you know.

Comment: Yep.. I have done this before. Let me know if you find any trouble implementing this.

Comment: When I specify the return as the line below cannot apply | operator to type string and string. Can you let me know the format which needs to send the messageback                                       return Json(new { "error"|ex.Message }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

Comment: Why don't you try returning ContentResult? Json parsing is also a overhead. Try return new ContentResult{content="error|"+ex.Message};

Comment: It's absolutely working fine Gaurav. Thanks so much for faster and timely response.

Comment: Glad that it helped @vishnureghu :) By the way as you are new, just to tell you, you should "mark as answer" to the one which you find correct.

Comment: @vishnureghu: you can see a 'tick mark' kind of button at left to every answer to the questions you have asked. You should always 'tick' the one that you find helpful.